# Write 'custom request handler' in solr

Tags: solr

I have to write custom request handler for solr.

Ok , I got the APIs , I wrote the very basic code.
But I don't know where I have to keep my .java file to get all imports like 'RequestHandlerBase' class.
I am getting hell lot of import error.

I have downloaded solr 4.2.1. Do I need to download something else also to get my handler compiled.

Can any one give me 'quick' step for 'compile' my java file ?

Thanks
for 
Any HElP

EDITED:
I am trying to compile using simple javac command.

Comment: This has little to do with solr - it's basic Java: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html for javac command options, but I suggest using an IDE such as Netbeans or Eclipse

Comment: No no ... may be I am missing base classes that comes with Solr. Obviously man I know java but I am missing solr classes somewhere .. :) ..

Answer (score 0):

Add **solr-core-4.2.1.jar** to your classpath, this is where org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase is located.

The Jar comes with the binary distribution of Solr 4.2.x

Comment: I did try , But after that I got import errors like 'org.apache.solr.common.<some file here>'  not found .. and more for lucene package .. :(

Comment: You can find the other missing libraries in the `contrib` and `dist` folders of the Solr install directory.

Comment: Please update your questions with specific error messages. It is impossible for us to help you, if all the info we have is that some file was not found. Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions on how to ask questions on SO. Thanks

Comment: Your are welcome. Don't forget to vote/accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

ok , I got my answer .. Well Simply downloaded source code for Solr.
using eclipse created a project sya name 'solr'.
Then in Drag and drop 'org' packages to eclipse. 
Then it is not showing any error while importing obviously becuase now I have base classes in my work place.